# MATLAB Serial communication with Arduino,fwrite function doesnt. Works with fprintf

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I am trying to control the robot based on Arduino microcontroller using serial port. The robot runs with the following code perfectly fine:

```
clear;
clc;
s=serial ('COM19');
set(s,'BaudRate',115200);
fopen(s);
fprintf(s,'%d',0);
fprintf(s,'%c',13);
fprintf(s,'%d',256);
fprintf(s,'%c',13);
fprintf(s,'%d',512);
fprintf(s,'%c',13);
fprintf(s,'%d',1000);
fprintf(s,'%c',13);
fclose(s);
delete(s);
```

However when I try to make it work with fread the %d equivalent statement doesn't work. However using fwrite(s,13,'uchar') in place of fprintf(s,'%c',13) works fine. I am not understanding which data type to replace %d with (i tried 'int')and what is the problem. If anyone has any suggestions it would be of great help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The subject is explained in Matlab documentation:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/writing-and-reading-data.html

> fprintf - Write text to the device
>   fwrite - Write binary data to the device

It's also stated:

> By default, fprintf writes data using the %s\n format...
>   Note that the ValuesSent property value includes the terminator because each occurrence of \n in the command sent to the device is replaced with the Terminator property value.

According to the documentation above, using `fprintf` command adds `\n` to the end of the transmitted text.  `\n` in uint8 format equals 10.

Example of difference between binary and text data:
`fwrite(s, 'A', 'uchar')` sends single byte with the value 65 (ASCII value of 'A').
`fprintf(s, "%c", 'A')` sends two bytes: 65 10 (10 is a terminator).
`fprintf(s,'%d',100);` sends bytes: 49   48   48   10 (49 is ASCII value of '1').
`fwrite(s, 100, 'uchar');` sends one byte equals: 100

In case you are using `Serial.read()` for reading a single byte in the Arduino software, the Arduino expects binary data format.
You can use `fwrite` command in Matlab for transmitting binary data.
Using `fwrite` for sending integer values above 255 (sending two bytes in `uint16` format for example) needs some extra work in the Arduino side, Arduino software needs to expect receiving two bytes, and treat them as single `uint16` element.

In case you prefer working with text data (use `fprintf` in Matlab), you should modify the Arduino software to read text (ASCII) format.
See: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadASCIIString